# C# Can you serialise a class from within that class

Tags: c#, oop, serialization

```
using somthing.Pakages;

namespace somthing.Entity
{
public class SomeClass
{

    // Data from new quote
    public string SomeData;

    public string SomeData;

    public string SomeData;

    public string SomeData;

    public int SomeData;

    public int SomeData;

    public int SomeData;

    public int SomeData;

    public bool SomeData;

    public string SomeData;

    public LifePolicy[] SomeData;

    public CiPolicy[] SomeData;

    public int SomeData;

    public SomeData()
    {

    }

    public void Save()
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(ApplicantId)){
            GuidCreator guidCreator = new GuidCreator();
            ApplicantId = guidCreator.GetGuid();
        }
        string serialization = ""; // On this line i want this var as a serialisation of this class with its vales
        DataSaver dataSaver = new DataSaver("Applicant", ApplicantId, serialization);
    }

}
```

}

How would i set the string serialization = to a string/json of this class as i need to save that data as a file but im not sure how i get this class into a string so it can be used.

Any help would be amazing thanks!

Comment: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this)`...

Comment: `string serialization =  JsonConvert.Serialize(this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit & download: 
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Then: 
myString =  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this)

Comment: would i use "this" or the name of the obejct?

Comment: When i just pass in the object name i get "class name not valid at this point"

Comment: @TomRouse: Your question in comment makes me think that you should (re)read the documentation on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this). Understanding why `this` should be used, involves understanding OOP principles (as `this` is a way to disambiguate otherwise ambiguous code).